# Program to find how an program launched

Tags: windows

I have a problem with my computer, sometimes, 2 webpages randomly opens even tough i do nothing (apolloprogram.com/opt-out and andara.com if I remember..) and I'm looking for a program that can tell me what opened theses web pages..

I already searched for a program like this but I couldn't find anything helpful..

So, any help would be great, thanks!

(PS : Sorry for my bad english, I'm french!)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To monitor the computer, you may use
[Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

For instructions on using it, see for example
[How To: Use Process Monitor To Capture System Events](https://forums.ivanti.com/s/article/How-To-Use-Process-Monitor-To-Capture-System-Events?language=en_US).

Process Monitor creates a huge log file which you can examine
with filters.
You would need to set up a filter to select the events that
interest you.

This filter might be *Operation > is > Process Start* or
*Process Create*.

Comment: Thank you very much!